# Processing CQEngine ResultSet with Scala foreach is very slow

Tags: java, scala, foreach

I'm trying to process CQEngine's ResultSet using Scala's foreach, but the result is very slow.

Following is the snippet of what I'm trying to do

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
val query = existIn(myOtherCollection, REFERENCE, REFERENCE)
val resultSet = myIndexCollection.retrieve(query)
resultSet.foreach(r =>{
    //do something here
})
```

Somehow the .foreach method is very slow. I tried to debug by putting SimonMonitor and change the .foreach using `while(resultSet.hasNext)`, surprisingly, every call to hasNext method takes about 1-2 seconds. That's very slow.

I tried to create the same version using Java, and the Java version is super fast.

Please help

Comment: Can you post more code? I can't understand why using a direct `hasNext` which is implemented in Java would somehow be slower just because you're calling it from a Scala code base. There's got to be something more you're doing.

Comment: @wheaties That's what I was thinking too, but I just couldn't find where my mistake is. I'll post more code when I get into office.

Comment: ok, ping me so I know to check this question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not able to reproduce your problem with the below test code. Can you try it on your system and let me know how it runs?

(Uncomment line 38, `garages.addIndex(HashIndex.onAttribute(Garage.BRANDS_SERVICED))`, to make BOTH the Scala and Java iterators run blazingly fast...)

The output first (time in milliseconds):

```
Done adding data
Done adding index
============== Scala ============== 
Car{carId=4, name='BMW M3', description='2013 model', features=[radio, convertible]}
Time : 3 seconds
Car{carId=1, name='Ford Focus', description='great condition, low mileage', features=[spare tyre, sunroof]}
Time : 1 seconds
Car{carId=2, name='Ford Taurus', description='dirty and unreliable, flat tyre', features=[spare tyre, radio]}
Time : 2 seconds
============== Java ============== 
Car{carId=4, name='BMW M3', description='2013 model', features=[radio, convertible]}
Time : 3 seconds
Car{carId=1, name='Ford Focus', description='great condition, low mileage', features=[spare tyre, sunroof]}
Time : 1 seconds
Car{carId=2, name='Ford Taurus', description='dirty and unreliable, flat tyre', features=[spare tyre, radio]}
Time : 2 seconds
```

Code below:

```
import collection.JavaConversions._
import com.googlecode.cqengine.query.QueryFactory._
import com.googlecode.cqengine.CQEngine;
import com.googlecode.cqengine.index.hash._;
import com.googlecode.cqengine.IndexedCollection;
import com.googlecode.cqengine.query.Query;
import java.util.Arrays.asList;

object CQTest {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val cars: IndexedCollection[Car] = CQEngine.newInstance();
    cars.add(new Car(1, "Ford Focus", "great condition, low mileage", asList("spare tyre", "sunroof")));
    cars.add(new Car(2, "Ford Taurus", "dirty and unreliable, flat tyre", asList("spare tyre", "radio")));
    cars.add(new Car(3, "Honda Civic", "has a flat tyre and high mileage", asList("radio")));
    cars.add(new Car(4, "BMW M3", "2013 model", asList("radio", "convertible")));

    // add cruft to try and slow down CQE
    for (i <- 1 to 10000) {
      cars.add(new Car(i, "BMW2014_" + i, "2014 model", asList("radio", "convertible")))
    }

    // Create an indexed collection of garages...
    val garages: IndexedCollection[Garage] = CQEngine.newInstance();
    garages.add(new Garage(1, "Joe's garage", "London", asList("Ford Focus", "Honda Civic")));
    garages.add(new Garage(2, "Jane's garage", "Dublin", asList("BMW M3")));
    garages.add(new Garage(3, "John's garage", "Dublin", asList("Ford Focus", "Ford Taurus")));
    garages.add(new Garage(4, "Jill's garage", "Dublin", asList("Ford Focus")));

    // add cruft to try and slow down CQE
    for (i <- 1 to 10000) {
      garages.add(new Garage(i, "Jill's garage", "Dublin", asList("DONT_MATCH_CARS_BMW2014_" + i)))
    }

    println("Done adding data")
    // cars.addIndex(HashIndex.onAttribute(Car.NAME));
    // garages.addIndex(HashIndex.onAttribute(Garage.BRANDS_SERVICED));
    println("Done adding index")
    val query = existsIn(garages, Car.NAME, Garage.BRANDS_SERVICED, equal(Garage.LOCATION, "Dublin"))
    val resultSet = cars.retrieve(query)

    var previous = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println("============== Scala ============== ")
    // Scala version
    resultSet.foreach(r => {
      println(r);
      val t = (System.currentTimeMillis() - previous)
      System.out.println("Time : " + t / 1000 + " seconds")
      previous = System.currentTimeMillis()
    })

    println("============== Java ============== ")
    previous = System.currentTimeMillis()
    // Java version
    val i: java.util.Iterator[Car] = resultSet.iterator()
    while (i.hasNext) {
      val r = i.next()
      println(r);
      val t = (System.currentTimeMillis() - previous)
      System.out.println("Time : " + t / 1000  + " seconds")
      previous = System.currentTimeMillis()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mentioned that I'm trying to query from 2 IndexCollection. So the existsIn is used to query cars in collection 1 that also exists in collection 2 based on the attribute in your case is Car.NAME. I'll try to post more code tomorrow when I reach office

Comment: I updated the code to a) do a exists-based join b) add a lot of cruft + NOT add an index so that CQEngine is forced to take time. In this case, both Scala and Java seem to take 1 to 3 seconds per lookup. If you add the index, `garages.addIndex(HashIndex.onAttribute(Garage.BRANDS_SERVICED))`, line 38, both Scala and Java finish the queries near-instantaneously...Do try this on your system and see if it gives you any insights into what is different about your code...?

Comment: Thanks for your updated code. There are 3 more things that can simulate my code.

1. The field being matched is created randomly using 5 characters alphanumeric (just upper case to make it easy) on object in both collections
2. Submit 1 million object on both IndexCollection.
3. Replace your existIn query to existsIn(garages, Car.NAME, Garage.BRANDS_SERVICED), just 3 parameters. I.e. remove your 4th parameter.

That'll really simulate my code

Comment: I made those 3 changes and both versions are equally fast (with an addIndex()! :-( My guess is that your Scala code is missing the addIndex() while the Java code (probably in a separate file) has an addIndex()?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right direction. What happen was that in Java I added the index in the constructor, while in scala, I did add the index, but it was never executed because I put it in a method resembling the class name (which I thought it is a constructor similar to Java).
You didn't exactly my issue but you've pointed me to the right direction, so I'll award the bounty to you.
Merry Christmas and Happy New Year!!!

Comment: That's great!! Thanks for the bounty! Merry Christmas, too! :-)